# Div over an image with the responsive height of image, bootstrap 4.3.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I made two layers over an image, one is a filter that's making the image dimmer and the second one is the content which has some random text.
I'd like to align them the same as image with the same width and height but kind of I don't know how to do that. I've also tried to make in CSS `background-image: url('...')` but it didn't worked either.

When I change the widths and heights of the browser window it all doesn't work... The layers have the fixed 632px and I don't know how to set to them the amount of height relative to the height of image.

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

ul {
  background: #eee !important;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul>li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  outline: none;
}

p {
  font-size: 115%;
}


/*header a*/

.nav-item a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000 !important;
  background: #d1de4c;
}

.header-container {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.presentation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 632px;
}

.img-content {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.img-filtr {
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.45;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-item.active>a {
  color: #d1de4c;
}

.col-12 {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body id="home" data-target=".navigation" data-offset="0" data-spy="scroll">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <header class="header-container sticky-top">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzk7J.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                        </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#home">STRONA GŁÓWNA <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#firma">O FIRMIE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#oferta">OFERTA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#etapy">ETAPY SPRZĄTANIA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#opinie">OPINIE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#kontakt">KONTAKT</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="presentation">
          <div class="img-content">Some text, styling not finished</div>
          <div class="img-filtr"></div>
          <img style="z-index:0;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNDW6.jpg" class="img-fluid img-in-placeholder">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Full screen, the layer with text and filter are not well aligned: [image: Full screen, the layer with text and filtr are not well aligned]

When I change the window aspect it goes even worse: [image: When I change the window aspect it goes even worse]

Comment: Why don't you use a `<div>` with `background-image` and `background-size: cover` in place of `<img>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `height` of `presentation` 100% and give it `position: relative` - this would allow the *absolutely positioned* child to position relative to this element - see demo below:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background: #fff;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

header {
  background: #eee;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

ul {
  background: #eee !important;
}

header a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

header ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

ul {
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: 10px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 85%;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 0;
}

ul>li {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

a {
  outline: none;
}

p {
  font-size: 115%;
}


/*header a*/

.nav-item a {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 25px 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.nav-item a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000 !important;
  background: #d1de4c;
}

.header-container {
  padding-top: 6px;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.presentation {
  width: 100%;
  /*height: 632px;*/
  height: 100%; /* ADDED */
  position: relative; /* ADDED */
}

.img-content {
  z-index: 2;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.img-filtr {
  z-index: 1;
  background: black;
  opacity: 0.45;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.nav-item.active>a {
  color: #d1de4c;
}

.col-12 {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i,700&amp;subset=latin-ext" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="home" data-target=".navigation" data-offset="0" data-spy="scroll">

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <header class="header-container sticky-top">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#home"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fzk7J.png" class="img-fluid"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                                    </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
              <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item active">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#home">STRONA GŁÓWNA <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#firma">O FIRMIE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#oferta">OFERTA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#etapy">ETAPY SPRZĄTANIA</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#opinie">OPINIE</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="#kontakt">KONTAKT</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </header>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="presentation">
          <div class="img-content">Some text, styling not finished</div>
          <div class="img-filtr"></div>
          <img style="z-index:0;" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PNDW6.jpg" class="img-fluid img-in-placeholder">
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```